# Configuring audio codec on Espressif ESP32-LYRATD-MSC Development Board

Tags: c, audio, embedded, audio-recording, esp32

When I compile and flash an ESP32-LYRATD-MSC with the [official audio recording examples](https://github.com/espressif/esp-adf/blob/master/examples/recorder/pipeline_raw_http/main/record_raw_http.c), I get an `es_write_reg` error after configuring the ES8388 codec driver.

What could have changed from the LYRA or WROVER kits to the LYRATD-MSC that could cause the error?

Comment: This seems a bit board for stack exchange - you are basically asking someone to point you at working code (or write it for you) rather than to help you find a *specific* problem in *specific* code.   You are more likely to get a useful result at the git issue where you already posted.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, SE was founded exactly to unearth solutions that used to be hidden away in forums and issue trackers. I've since answered my question, which linked to a specific C file that was unsupported by the manufacturer in the official repos and where the problem got few eyeballs. Of course, I would love to receive working code as answers to all my questions - wouldn't you? :)

Comment: @ChrisStratton I've edited my question now that I know the nature of the problem.

Comment: Ironically, it looks like your original post had some of the missing information which you have now removed.

Comment: @ChrisStratton if a code sample, specific hardware model code and error message is not enough detail for you, we'll have to agree to disagree. I moved the link to the known incompatibility to my answer because it puts the solution in context and having it in my question made it seem like I knew the solution when I posted, when I did not.

Comment: You've turned the question from one asked by a *developer working the problem* with deductive evidence included to one by an end *user* throwing up their hands and hoping to be rescued.  That's off topic here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/espressif/esp-adf/issues/18) with the samples. The ESP32-LYRATD-MSC ships with the ZL38063 DSP chip, but as you can see from sample, it expects to configure the ESP8388:

```
audio_hal_codec_config_t audio_hal_codec_cfg =  AUDIO_HAL_ES8388_DEFAULT(); // offending line
audio_hal_codec_cfg.i2s_iface.samples = AUDIO_HAL_16K_SAMPLES;
audio_hal_handle_t hal = audio_hal_init(&audio_hal_codec_cfg, 0);
audio_hal_ctrl_codec(hal, AUDIO_HAL_CODEC_MODE_ENCODE, AUDIO_HAL_CTRL_START);
```

To resolve, configure for the ZL38063 instead:

```
audio_hal_handle_t init_audio_codec()
{
#if (CONFIG_ESP_LYRAT_V4_3_BOARD || CONFIG_ESP_LYRAT_V4_2_BOARD)
    audio_hal_codec_config_t audio_hal_codec_cfg = AUDIO_HAL_ES8388_DEFAULT();
    return audio_hal_init(&audio_hal_codec_cfg, 0);
#endif

#if (CONFIG_ESP_LYRATD_MSC_V2_1_BOARD || CONFIG_ESP_LYRATD_MSC_V2_2_BOARD)
    audio_hal_codec_config_t audio_hal_codec_cfg = AUDIO_HAL_ZL38063_DEFAULT();
    return audio_hal_init(&audio_hal_codec_cfg, 2);
#endif
}
```

### Then, in `app_main()`:

```
audio_hal_ctrl_codec(init_audio_codec(), AUDIO_HAL_CODEC_MODE_BOTH, AUDIO_HAL_CTRL_START);
```

Comment: Good answer to an improper question